# Pandas: parsing corrupted .xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to read .xls files and extract tables into df.(I can open it with Excel, but it gives me a pop up: *.xls file cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only exception.* ).

In general properties its Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls)

Code:

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
from os import walk


file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 

excels = [pd.read_excel(name) for name in file_path]  

df = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels] #Error

df.to_excel("Final.xls", header=False, index=False)
```

Error:

```
pd.ExcelFile(name) :

    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xc1\xc5  \t\xc7\xed\xcf'

or  (with rea_html)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 545, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

However as the error message says, the first 8 bytes of the file are '\xc1\xc5' ... that is definitely not Excel .xls format...

Is it any way to proceed such files?

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  If YOU can't even figure out what the data is, then you can't tell the computer how to do it.  I would point out that you are not limiting your search to `.xls` files.  You're trying to open everything.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good point, thanks, I fixed the code to make it more appealing. I have only xls files in folder, so I am reading only them. How can I figure out what the data is, if file opens normally and works in Exel\ Hex editors?

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that Excel is able to open it after complaining.  The old Office documents all start with hex D0 CF 11 E0.  Without having the file, I couldn't guess.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am new to these Pandas things; the first thing I realize is there is a syntax error down below. It should have been "pd.read_excel".

excels = [pd.read_exel(name) for name in file_path]

The second thing I can say is; corrupted xls files could be read by "pd.read_html()". I hope it helps.